# Facebook Authentication using cURL (php)

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I'm *trying* to use cURL to do facebook authentication and here's what I have:

```
        $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
        $postString = "?client_id=$client_id&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri&client_secret=$client_secret&code=$code";
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

but every time it just returns false.

I'm pretty new to using cURL so I could be making some beginner mistakes, but I'm confused as to why this isn't working at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Solved it, it was an ssl issue combined with a typo in my $postString var (the '?' at the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too obvious and it may be a typo, but:

`//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`

Should be uncommented.

Comment: I was just testing both GET and POST to see whether it made a difference, I happened to have just tested GET before I copy pasted the code here :)

Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: If I were you, I would debug like this: `FAILONERROR` should be taken out, or commented. And the '?' in the `$postString` taken out (I believe). Does it give any kind of response, or is `$response` empty?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "?" from the beginning of your post string.. that should fix it!